# Sumar items en array aleatoriamente

Tags: javascript

Se cómo sumar el total de elementos en un array de forma ordenada:

```js
var numbers = [1,4,6,2]; 

 1+4+6+2 // resultado = 13
```

Pero y aleatoriamente y comprobar en cada suma, si el resultado es uno determinado?

```js
var sumarArray = [1,4,6,2]; 

 1+6 (comprobar con un If si el resultado es x)
 1+2 (volver a comprobar)
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```js
for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    numbers = numbers.slice(i, 1)
        if (sum === result){
           // break;
        }
        else{
            for (let j=0; j<numbers.length;j++){
                //numbers.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5 });

            }
        }
   }

   return numbers
```

Dónde necesito ayuda es como implementar la función `sort()` que he cojido de otro sitio, y como meterle el condicional dentro de ella

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo, lo que quieres hacer es coger dos elementos del `Array` aleatorios y sumarlos. ¿No? ¿Y después comprobar si la suma es igual a 'n'?

Comment: Si, exactamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más fácil que tienes de hacer esto es eligiendo dós índices aleatorios del array usando `Math.random()` y `Math.round()` (este último para obtener los números enteros). Y encapsulando los valores en una función, después haces con el valor de retorno de esta función lo que quieras, compararlo con un if, por ejemplo.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que puedas probar.

```js
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const sumArray = myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr); // 55

const sumRandomArray = array => {
  const randomIndex1 = Math.round(Math.random()*(array.length-1));
  let randomIndex2;
  do {
    randomIndex2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(array.length-1));
  } while (randomIndex1 === randomIndex2);
  
  
  console.log(`Los índices aleatorios seleccionados son: ${randomIndex1} y ${randomIndex2}`)
  console.log(`Los valores seleccionados son: ${array[randomIndex1]} y ${array[randomIndex2]}`)
  return array[randomIndex1] + array[randomIndex2];
}

console.log(`La suma total de elementos en el array es: ${sumArray}`);
console.log(sumRandomArray(myArray));
console.log(sumRandomArray(myArray));
console.log(sumRandomArray(myArray));
console.log(sumRandomArray(myArray));
```

Comment: Gracias,por qué el "-1" en Math.round(Math.random()*(array.length-1)); ?

Comment: @JavierCake Por que el `.length` de un `array` te devuelve el tamaño en números desde el 1. Pero el `index` de un `array` tiene en cuenta el 0. si lo harías sin el -1 estaría intentado entrar a la posición 10 del `array` y te daría un "index out of bounds" o "undefined" porque el último index de tu array es 9